# How to use a QTreeView Model to display a list of files/folders get through mtp stack

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, model, qtreeview

I'm currently building an application which need to access to a device through the MTP stack.

I'm developping the code in c++ and Qt to easily be able to port the code on different platform.

I have based the Ui on TreeView to display the folder and ListView to display the list of files of the selected folder.

Most of example are using :

```
model->setRootPath("F:/Qt/GUI/files"); 
treeView->setModel(model); 
treeView->setRootIndex(model->index("F:/Qt/GUI/files"));
```

All these models are based on model which accessing to the local HD but in my case, I need to do it through list of folders/files using MTP Api. The backend is working, I mean accessing to the device is ok but I'm still thinkin on how to display the tree of folder and create a model.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please, refer to the [Qt Model/View tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html) and [Model/View programming](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

In general you shall create [new model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#creating-new-models) and in the bare minimum override a couple of pure virtual functions.
Since it's a Tree structure, you should subclass QAbstractItemModel.